# Scala - Implement Object Factory Pattern

Tags: scala, class

I am trying to implement object factory design pattern in scala. However I am not able to undertand how to return the object based on condition.

I tried to return `Option` however it's not working as expected.

```scala
import java.io.File
import java.util.Properties

import scala.io.Source

abstract class FileSystem {
  def moveFile(propFileURI: String): Unit
}

object FileSystem {

  private class HDFSystem extends FileSystem{
    override def moveFile(propFileURI: String): Unit = {
      println(" HDFS  move file")
    }
  }

  private class S3System extends FileSystem {
    override def moveFile(propFileURI: String): Unit = {
      println("S3 Move File ")
    }
  }

  // How to handle this??
  def apply(propFileURI: String): Option[FileSystem] = {
    val properties: Properties = new Properties()

    val source = Source.fromFile( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\"+propFileURI).reader
    properties.load(source)
    val srcPath = properties.getProperty("srcPath")
    val destPath = properties.getProperty("destPath")

    var Obj = None:Option[FileSystem]

    if (destPath.contains("hdfs")){
      Obj = Option(new HDFSystem())
    }
    if (srcPath.contains("s3") && destPath.contains("s3")){
     Obj = Option(new S3System())
    }
    Obj
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val obj = FileSystem("test.properties")
    obj match {
      case test: FileSystem => test.moveFile("test.properties")
      case None => None
    }

  }
}
```

How to handle the `Apply` method based on condition I have mentioned? Do I really need to return `option` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Option`s aren't Java's `@nullable`s. You pattern match on `Some` if value is present:

```
    val obj = FileSystem("test.properties") // Option[FileSystem]
    obj match {
      case Some(test) => test.moveFile("test.properties")
      case None       =>
    }
```

Also in Scala almost everything is an expression so `if-else`, blocks, loops and functions returns their last value as the value of all. Also we should take IO errors into consideration, so `Try` could be better than `Option`:

```
  def apply(propFileURI: String): Try[FileSystem] =
    Try {
      // reading properties could fail
      val p = new Properties()
      val source = Source.fromFile( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\"+propFileURI).reader
      p.load(source)
      p
    }.flatMap { properties =>
      // reading from properties could fail
      val srcPath = properties.getProperty("srcPath")
      val destPath = properties.getProperty("destPath")

      if (destPath.contains("hdfs")) Success(new HDFSystem())
      else if (srcPath.contains("s3") && destPath.contains("s3")) Success(new S3System())
      else Failure(new Exception("Unable to recognize filesystem"))
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    FileSystem("test.properties") match {
      case Success(fileSystem) => fileSystem.moveFile("test.properties")
      case Failure(error)      => error.printStackTrace()
    }
```

We could convert `Try` at any moment to `Option` with `.toOption` and pattern-match on it. But this way we have no information on error. We could also create a `FileSystemError` type for storing error information and return `Either[FileSystemError, FileSystem]` instead of `Try`. Lastly, we could just throw `Exception`, but this way we return to Java-like practices that doesn't tell us that error can happen, and it surprises us at runtime.

What I would surely do is to rename `apply` - we usually expect object's apply to always return success, so if it isn't possible and we use some sort of smart constructor we should give it some other name. E.g. here we could name it

```
def resolveFor(propFileURI: String): Either[FileSystemError, FileSystem] = ...
```

so that everyone using it would know what behavior expect just from the signature.

Comment: I'm wondering why did you use `flatMap` instead of placing the whole code in `Try`'s `apply` method? Nice usage of `Try` though!

Comment: Technically, I could. I initially used `locally` to limit scope of `Properties` and later on I started rewriting it. `.flatMap` was also a way of avoid `throw`ing.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to clean up your implementation, for example, usage of `var` could be avoided

```
if (destPath.contains("hdfs"))
  Some(new HDFSystem())
else if (srcPath.contains("s3") && destPath.contains("s3")) 
  Some(new S3System())
else 
  None
```

however as far as I understand the main point of the question is

> Do I really need to return `Option`?

This is a design decision with tradeoffs and no clear answer. Ask yourself how should the system react if `.properties` file is missing the appropriate configuration key:

- Could we construct a meaningful default `FileSystem` object? In this case there is no need for `Option`, just return the default and continue processing.
- If we cannot construct a meaningful default, is there any point in continuing? Should the system crash? In which case we might throw.
- If the system can continue operating despite not being able to construct `FileSystem`, then we could model this information as `Option` or `Either` etc., perhaps log the event, and continue processing.

These are just some considerations to take into account. Personally, I have found that a misconfigured system is hard to recover from.

Comment: I agree about the misconfigured system (+1). Maybe a good choice would be to use cats' `Validated` instead of `Either` to fail-slow. That way we can gather all (or at least more than single one) configuration errors at single run.